# Вытащить конкретные данные из JSON (php) (мало кода)

Tags: php, массивы, json

Всем доброго времени суток. Учусь работать с API. В процессе мне пришли данные формата JSON, с помощью

```
    $inv = json_decode($url);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($inv);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Я получил данные вот в таком формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все эти данные мне не нужны, а нужны только выборочные. Можно ли как-то вывести на экран только [id] или например только [classid] ? И если можно, то как, подскажите ?

Всё что пытался делать сам, выдавало только ошибки ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// 2й параметр == true => "возвращать как массив" / false => "как объект"
$inv = json_decode($url, true);

foreach($inv['rgInventory'] as $key => $item) {
    var_dump($key, $item['id'], $item['classid']);
}
```

Справка

- [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Если вы не бог, то кто тогда ... 10/10. Всё работает.