# Выбрать данные из JSON (php)

Tags: php, массивы, json

```
print_r($json);
```

Выдаёт мне:

```
{
"items_game": {
    "game_info": {
        "first_valid_class": "1",
        "last_valid_class": "1000",
        "first_valid_item_slot": "0",
        "last_valid_item_slot": "15",
        "num_item_presets": "4"
    },
    "rarities": {
        "common": {
            "value": "1",
            "loc_key": "Rarity_Common",
            "color": "desc_common",
            "next_rarity": "uncommon"
        },
        "uncommon": {
            "value": "2",
            "loc_key": "Rarity_Uncommon",
            "color": "desc_uncommon",
            "next_rarity": "rare"
        },
        "rare": {
            "value": "3",
            "loc_key": "Rarity_Rare",
            "color": "desc_rare",
            "next_rarity": "mythical"
        },
```

Можно ли получить из этого массива только значения "value" и "color" ? Если можно, то подскажите пожалуйста как ... Пытаюсь сделать через

```
       foreach($json['items_game'] as $key => $item) {
            echo $item['value'];
        }
```

Но мне сразу выдаёт две ошибки, пытался менять но ничего не оплучается:

```
llegal string offset 'items_game' 
invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: `json_decode`. Дефолтно всё парсится в `stdClass`, отсюда ошибки. Чтобы преобразовать в массив, установите второй аргумент функции в `true`. И приведите пример того, что Вам нужно получить в итоге, а то как-то неясно.

Comment: а вам разве наглядно тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565648/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json-php-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0 не объяснили процесс выборки?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Тот код в этом примере не работает и выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @BimBam логично, данные то поменялись, но способ же не изменился... или вам на каждый массив надо по вопросы создать и по ответу получить? Если вы не способны это сделать, то у меня для вас плохие новости

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский а вы посомтрите на тот код, и на этот. Там какие-то классы задействованы и синтаксис вообще другой. А тут не так всё.

Comment: @BimBam  я отлично вижу что у вас......и там и тут JSON. Там у вас выдавал stdClass т.к. вы у `json_decode` вторым параметром не поставили `true` ..... здесь вы делаете всё тоже самое..пытаетесь взять значение из json'a ...... беретеся оно также, как указано в прошлом вопросе-ответе....`json_decode` с `true` только изменены ключи и значения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я вызываю JSON-файл `$item_list = file_get_contents("items_game.json");` $item_list
на экран выводит то, что написано сверху. Но когда я делаю '$arr = json_decode($item_list, true);', то $arr уже на экран не выводится, как будто его нет.

Comment: @BimBam оке, если проблема в том что при декодировании ничего не выводится, то тогда причем тут вопрос про foreach? логично что он не будет работать.... А догадаться, что у вас оказывается в $arr ничего нет по коду предоставленному в вопросе - как-то проблематично, вы не находите?.Проблема одна, а вопрос со всем о другом........... а после `json_decode` не выводит ничего потому что видимо json не валидный.. если он такой как в вопросе - то 100% невалид.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а в чём заключается его невалидность ?

Comment: Поддерживаю комментарий @АлексейШиманский, вопрос составлен некорректно. Приведите полный пример вашего json, здесь похоже на какой-то выдернутый обрезанный кусок.

Comment: @5f0f5048ff дело в том, что я получил данные в формате vdf valve data format) и с помощью кода переконвертировал его в json. Получилось то, что я скинул.

Comment: @BimBam не хватает как минимум трех закрывающих фигурных скобки ...... вот киньте свой json в http://json.parser.online.fr/  и вас он пошлет матом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там более 50 000 строк JSON'a. Я же не могу все их скинуть, до последней скобки.

Comment: @BimBam ну тогда сами проверьте на валидность)) Если он не валиден, то конечно же остальной код по парсингу json и цикл не будет работать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский проверил, JSON валидный. В чём ещё может быть причина ?

Comment: @BimBam зачем вы там что то куда то конвертируете, получите от steam api валидный json, и дальше действуйте как вам ниже написали. Что бы от самого steam получить json допишите в ссылке `&format=json`, и не мучайте людей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправленный json

```
{
    "items_game": {
        "game_info": {
            "first_valid_class": "1",
            "last_valid_class": "1000",
            "first_valid_item_slot": "0",
            "last_valid_item_slot": "15",
            "num_item_presets": "4"
        },
        "rarities": {
            "common": {
                "value": "1",
                "loc_key": "Rarity_Common",
                "color": "desc_common",
                "next_rarity": "uncommon"
            },
            "uncommon": {
                "value": "2",
                "loc_key": "Rarity_Uncommon",
                "color": "desc_uncommon",
                "next_rarity": "rare"
            },
            "rare": {
                "value": "3",
                "loc_key": "Rarity_Rare",
                "color": "desc_rare",
                "next_rarity": "mythical"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Конвертируем json в массив.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

Затем пробегаем по массиву циклом.

```
foreach ($arr['items_game']['rarities'] as $key => $value) {
    echo("VALUE -> " . $value['value'] . "<br>");
    echo("COLOR -> " . $value['color'] . "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Кусок вашего json невалидный, если добавить закрывающие скобки все работает.

Comment: дело в том, что полностью в этом коде 500 000 строк. И проверить его на валидность практически невозможно. Ладно, спасибо вам за всё, буду искать ошибку )